# Dis-assembly of same binaries showing different instrucions

Tags: assembly, arm, iar, thumb

I am using at91sam4e16e micro-controller in my application and bootloader example from 
ASF(xdk-1.15.0) for bootloader named starter_kit_bootloader_demo.

Now I haev customized the project for sam4e-ek I am trying to update binary from using that 
bootloader.

after updating I compared both binary files 1) updated [image: disassembly of bootloader binary]

and 2)standalone

[image]

both binaries are same 
but when I debug it in IAR the disassembly shows that instructions are different. why it is different?

Comment: How do you figure the binaries are the same, if the disassembly differs? How are you running ARM code on a Cortex-M4? _What is the actual question here?_

Comment: you can see in images from that both biaries are same at that address. still showing different instructions.

Comment: Well, they're the same except for all the bytes that are different, at any rate. Either way you have some data that in one case the disassembler has symbols for (so knows it's data), and in the other case doesn't (so tries to interpret it as nonsense instructions). I still don't see what this has to do with the title, and [_you still haven't actually asked a question_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I added the debug information from the original .out file into the new bootloader project. Now both disassembly of similar binaries are similar. It was interpreting the binary of vector table as some nonsense instructions as per [Notlikethat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156750/notlikethat) 's suggestion.

Comment: When looking at binaries without symbols, always pay as much attention to the raw bytes as to the disassembly - if you see something that looks like a valid address, it's probably an address (especially if it "disassembles" to something as clearly ridiculous as the example here)